# Promise does not resolve this

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

This simplified code:

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.promise = new Promise(async resolve => {
      this.resolve = resolve
    })
  }

  then() {
    this.promise.then(...arguments)
    this.resolve(this)
  }
}

const x = new A()
x.then(res => {
  console.log(res)
})
```

Fails to resolve.

If you change `this.resolve(this)` to `this.resolve('done')` it works.  Any ideas why?

Comment: You deleted your previous question ?

Comment: Yes I updated it to this one to make it clearer.

Comment: `setTimeout()` does not return a Promise

Comment: @Krishna Prashatt  - yes people were downvoting - so I redid it with a working example to clarify.

Comment: @Pointy - no - just run the code and then change it as I've indicated - one works the other not.

Comment: The point is that `await setTimeout()` does not make any sense

Comment: @TrevTheDev can you convert the code into a snippet?

Comment: @Pointy - I've removed the offending setTimeout - I put it in to mirror my code which was failing - but as your point out it is not relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The item being returned (the `this`) has a `.then` method, and the Promise resolver (`resolve`) sees that, thinks that you called it with a Promise, so it tries to resolve that Promise as well:

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.promise = new Promise(async resolve => {
      this.resolve = resolve
      await setTimeout(() => {
        this.x = 1
      }, 1000)
    })
  }

  then() {
    this.promise.then(...arguments)
    this.fin()
    console.log('then running');
  }

  fin() {
    this.resolve(this)
  }
}

const x = new A()
x.then(res => {
  console.log(res)
})
```

One possible solution would be to call `resolve` with an object which *wraps* the `this` instead, so that the resolver function doesn't see the `.then` method and try to unwrap it as well:

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.promise = new Promise(async resolve => {
      this.resolve = resolve
      await setTimeout(() => {
        this.x = 1
      }, 1000)
    })
  }

  then() {
    this.promise.then(...arguments)
    return this.fin();
  }

  fin() {
    this.resolve({ result: this })
  }
}

const x = new A()
x.then(res => {
  console.log(res.result)
})
```